# Nginx doesn't work with Sinatra JSON route

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger

I've setup a Ubuntu 16.04 server with Nginx 1.12.1 and installed and configured Phusion Passenger 5.1.8 (Open Source) to work correctly.

I've tested this with the [passenger-ruby-sinatra-demo](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-ruby-sinatra-demo) repo.

I've set the `root` var to the `/views` folder of the repo in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file:

```
root /var/www/passenger-ruby-sinatra-demo/views;
```

The `/views` folder contains one file called `index.erb`.

Here's the content of the `app.rb` file:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'json'

class ExampleApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end

  get '/hello' do
    content_type 'application/json'

    {'message'=>'hello world!'}.to_json
  end
end
```

So now when visiting `/` I see the html page. But when visiting `/hello` I get a 404 screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
When I add an empty folder called `hello` into the `views` folder, it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding the following to my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` config file (inside the `server` block):

```
...

location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
}

location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

...
```

And I deleted:

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

This was an Nginx config issue related to the deleted code above.